# Elasticsearch Jackson Date type

Tags: json, elasticsearch, jackson

I'm using elasticsearch in order to create my index.
Everything is fasty.

I chose jackson in order to generate elasticsearch index documents
So, I've created this serializer:

```
public class DigitalInputSerializer extends JsonSerializer<DigitalInput> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(DigitalInput value, JsonGenerator gen,
        SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException,
        JsonProcessingException {

        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeNumberField("timestamp", value.getTimestamp().getTime());   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        gen.writeStringField("matter", value.getMatter());
        gen.writeStringField("comment", value.getComment());
        gen.writeStringField("channel_id", value.getChannelId());
        gen.writeEndObject();

    }

}
```

I've had a surprise, when I looked for a `writeDateField`!!! It isn't there!
Then I chose to index this field using a long field, however I'm losing the date type indexable features that elasticsearch provides.

Could you help me, please?

Thanks for all.